# Missing final newline

Tags: dpkg, qemu

I'm very new to everything here and only got ubuntu today. Also I have no clue how to use the bit that makes it clear its code so apologies. I am trying to install `git` for a project and it says this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (> 1:2.30.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (< 1:2.30.2-.) but it is not going to be installed
 qemu-block-extra : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                             qemu-system-arm (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed or
                             qemu-system-mips (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed or
                             qemu-system-ppc (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed or
                             qemu-system-sparc (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed or
                             qemu-system-misc (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed or
                             qemu-system-s390x (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed or
                             qemu-system-x86-xen (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not installable
 qemu-system-gui : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu2 is to be installed or
                            qemu-system-arm (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed or
                            qemu-system-mips (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed or
                            qemu-system-ppc (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed or
                            qemu-system-sparc (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed or
                            qemu-system-misc (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed or
                            qemu-system-s390x (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed or
                            qemu-system-x86-xen (= 1:5.2+dfsg-9ubuntu3) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I ran:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

and got this:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'qemu-block-extra' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Can anyone help? I know other people have this problem but with different what I'm guessing is the package (like I said, I'm new), where mine says `quemu-block-extra`.

Please dumb it down as much as possible for me.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1345319/edit) to include the instructions that you are following. Also, please specify exactly which release of Ubuntu you installed.

Comment: Looks a bit like broken apt repository data, does this issue remain after an `apt update` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone it was a problem with a corrupted SD card